# np.random.randint: ValueError: low >= high

Tags: python, dataframe

getting a high low error on this. Works with another 1D dataframe and dtype but not on this. I'm trying to create a list of means taken randomly from a 1D list. Thanks!

```
new = []
for x in df:
    sb_ = np.random.randint(x, size=100).mean()
    new.append(sb_)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`numpy.random` documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html). If only one input parameter is given as in your case, that input is the lower end of the range, and high is taken as 0. So, if any `x` in `df` is less than 0 (we'll say `x'`, this code tries to draw a random integer from the range [0,x'], which is an empty range (no possible values). Thus your high-low error.

Based on your code and description it's a bit unclear exactly what you're trying to accomplish but with a bit more detail I can probably help you work out the correct code.

Comment: Thanks DerekG. What I'm basically trying to accomplish is to create a new list of means derived from a list of numbers randomly. x is the list and size=100 is the sample size I want to get an average on.

Comment: If the list is constant, the mean of the list doesn't change does it?

Comment: What range do the values of `x` (i.e. the values in `df` fall in?

Comment: x is the list I want to get random numbers in order to get the mean. the mean taken randomly will be added to new. the new list will have new means everytime.

Comment: Yes but what range do the values of `x` fall in? For instance, say that the values of `x` fall between -10 and 10. It makes a lot of sense to say `np.random.randint(10,size = 100)` because this samples 100 random values between 0 and 10. However, it doesn't make sense to say `np.random.randint(-10,size = 100)` because this tries to sample 100 values greater than 0 and less than -10, which is not possible. Do you understand that?

Comment: Thanks again DerekG, I see what's going on. there were some entries which were strings and numbers less than 0. 'Not sure why I didn't catch that in the beginning as well. Explanation made sense to what I was doing. Thanks again!